# pxelinux hanging when booting client machine

Tags: linux, centos, virtualbox, syslinux

I'm kind of new to all of this, so please forgive any vagueness/misunderstandings on my part.

I'm using pxelinux and VMs to create CentOS 6.0 machines that have the same install every time. I have a new VM set to boot from network, but in the process of booting up it gets stuck at "Loading 10.1.1.20:/pxelinux.0" (10.1.1.20 is the address of the server it's getting info from).

pxelinux conf: http://pastebin.com/4XfZZPY1

I'm pretty sure all my config files are correct, could it be VirtualBox related?

I have both the building server and the new client set to Host-only adapter and PCNET-FAST.

Comment: is the tftp server a centos host? then you need to ensure the firewall en selinux settings are correct (or turn them off).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this once before, and I believe the solution was similar to this: http://forum.ipxe.org/archive/index.php/thread-5514.html
I had to switch network drivers on the guest VM to use the virtual Intel driver.

Also ,if you're running an old version of Virtual box, it seems like there was a bug with pxe boot in older versions. https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/2536

Comment: Thank you for your help. Updating my version of virtualbox worked (was using 4.1.10), but now it's getting stuck at the blue screen saying "Unable to download Kickstart file". I've got httpd running fine, the ipaddr of where it's getting the kickstart is correct, and I'm pretty sure all my pathways are right. Any thoughts?

Comment: Look at the firewall comment  above. Are you sure that the firewall permits you to download the kickstart file?

Comment: Sorry, I was convinced that my firewall was right. I put INPUT, OUTPUT, and FORWARD to ACCEPT with no other rules, and that seemed to work. Just out of curiosity, what would the firewall syntax be for letting the new build grab the kickstart? I had `-A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT`. Is that wrong, and do I need more? Here was my original iptables file `http://pastebin.com/R7SeH6JG`